# EnvDTE80.Window2' does not contain a definition for 'CreateToolWindow2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I am newbie on VS-2010 Add-Ins so I started with this walkthrough:

- [HOWTO: Create a dockable toolwindow from a Visual Studio .NET add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006007.aspx)

But when I am building my Project I get the following error:

> 'EnvDTE80.Window2' does not contain a definition for
>   'CreateToolWindow2' and no extension method 'CreateToolWindow2'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'EnvDTE80.Window2' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly)

I have added the assembly reference in my Project (actually the Add-In wizard did). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Windows2.CreateToolWindow2().  Note the s after "Window".